# TypeError between two instances of Vertices (nodes) in Dijkstra's SPF algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, shortest-path, dijkstra, heapq

I am currently working on solving a train schedule optimization problem as part of my studies. In this problem, a utility function has to be maximized which increases in the number of (critical) stations visited, and decreases in the amount of trains used and in the total amount of minutes the trains are running.

The problem consists of stations (nodes) and connections (edges). Data on both of these is first loaded from two CSV files. Then, classes are instantiated for each station (containing the name and whether or not it is critical), and each connection (containing the stations in the connection, and the time it costs to travel to one another). These stations and connection are both stored in dictionaries.

As a first step, my groupmates and I decided we first wanted to implement a version of Dijkstra's Pathfinding Algorithm in order to find the quickest route between two stations. [BogoToBogo](https://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_Dijkstras_Shortest_Path_Algorithm.php) has a very detailed guide on how to implement a version of Dijkstra's algorithm. We decided first to try and implement their code to see what the results would be. However, a TypeError keeps popping up:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Vertex' and 'Vertex'

If anyone has an idea what is causing this error, any help would be greatly appriciated!

```
#Makes the shortest path from v.previous
def shortest(v, path):
    if v.previous:
        path.append(v.previous.get_id())
        shortest(v.previous, path)
    return

def dijkstra(aGraph, start, target):
    print('Dijkstras shortest path')
    # Set the distance for the start node to zero
    start.set_distance(0)

# Put tuple pair into the priority queue
unvisited_queue = [(v.get_distance(),v) for v in aGraph]
heapq.heapify(unvisited_queue)

while len(unvisited_queue):
    # Pops a vertex with the smallest distance
    uv = heapq.heappop(unvisited_queue)
    current = uv[1]
    current.set_visited()

    #for next in v.adjacent:
    for next in current.adjacent:
        # if visited, skip
        if next.visited:
            continue
        new_dist = current.get_distance() + current.get_weight(next)

        if new_dist < next.get_distance():
            next.set_distance(new_dist)
            next.set_previous(current)
            print('updated : current = ' + current.get_id() + ' next = ' + next.get_id() + ' new_dist = ' + next.get_distance())

        else:
            print('not updated : current = ' + current.get_id() + ' next = ' + next.get_id() + ' new_dist = ' + next.get_distance())

    # Rebuild heap
    # 1. Pop every item
    while len(unvisited_queue):
        heapq.heappop(unvisited_queue)
    # 2. Put all vertices not visited into the queue
    unvisited_queue = [(v.get_distance(),v) for v in aGraph if not v.visited]
    heapq.heapify(unvisited_queue)

if __name__ == "__main__":

# Calling the CSV loading functions in mainActivity
# These functions will also instantiate station and connections objects
load_stations(INPUT_STATIONS)
load_connections(INPUT_CONNECTIONS)

g = Graph()

for index in stations:
    g.add_vertex(stations[index].name)

for counter in connections:
    g.add_edge(connections[counter].stat1, connections[counter].stat2, int(connections[counter].time))

for v in g:
    for w in v.get_connections():
        vid = v.get_id()
        wid = w.get_id()
        print( vid, wid, v.get_weight(w))

dijkstra(g, g.get_vertex('Alkmaar'), g.get_vertex('Zaandam'))

target = g.get_vertex('Zaandam')
path = [target.get_id()]
shortest(target, path)
print('The shortest path :' + (path[::-1]))
```

In this case, the function dijkstra is called, given the parameters g (which is a instance of the Graph class), Alkmaar, and Zaandam.

```
# Represents a grid of nodes/stations composed of nodes and edges
class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vert_dict = {}
        self.num_vertices = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.vert_dict.values())

    def add_vertex(self, node):
        self.num_vertices = self.num_vertices + 1
        new_vertex = Vertex(node)
        self.vert_dict[node] = new_vertex
        return new_vertex

    def get_vertex(self, n):
        if n in self.vert_dict:
            return self.vert_dict[n]
        else:
            return None

    def add_edge(self, frm, to, cost = 0):
        if frm not in self.vert_dict:
            self.add_vertex(frm)
        if to not in self.vert_dict:
            self.add_vertex(to)

        self.vert_dict[frm].add_neighbor(self.vert_dict[to], cost)
        self.vert_dict[to].add_neighbor(self.vert_dict[frm], cost)

    def get_vertices(self):
        return self.vert_dict.keys()

    def set_previous(self, current):
        self.previous = current

    def get_previous(self, current):
        return self.previous
```

The Graph class.

```
# Represents a node (station)
class Vertex:

    def __init__(self, node):
        self.id = node
        self.adjacent = {}
        # Set distance to infinity for all nodes
        self.distance = sys.maxsize
        # Mark all nodes unvisited
        self.visited = False
        # Predecessor
        self.previous = None

    def add_neighbor(self, neighbor, weight=0):
        self.adjacent[neighbor] = weight

    def get_connections(self):
        return self.adjacent.keys()

    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

    def get_weight(self, neighbor):
        return self.adjacent[neighbor]

    def set_distance(self, dist):
        self.distance = dist

    def get_distance(self):
        return self.distance

    def set_previous(self, prev):
        self.previous = prev

    def set_visited(self):
        self.visited = True

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + ' adjacent: ' + str([x.id for x in self.adjacent])
```

The Vertex class.
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might help, but the way when posting to stackoverflow just post as little and complete information as possible

```
# Put tuple pair into the priority queue
unvisited_queue = [(v.get_distance(),v) for v in aGraph]
heapq.heapify(unvisited_queue)
```

if you look at this code it converts the list to a heap which requires `<` comparison of whatever you give to it, define a  [`__gt__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.gt) method in the vertex class , the function will determine what gets popped first so write it as you see fit and I think the error will go away. :-)